# File iteration to search for similar phrases in node.js

Tags: node.js, file, loops, phrase

I have specific issue:

This function is responsible for reading file.

```
function readFile (email){
  fs.readFile('./files/data.json', 'utf8', (err, fileContents) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err)
      return
    }
    try {
      const data = fileContents
      console.log(data)
    } catch(err) {
      console.error(err)
    }
  })
    if(email = (how can iterate file in search of phrases?){
      console.log('identic')
    }
    else{
      console.log('ok')
    }
}
```

Also I getting request from client with **email** i pass this parameter to function as **email**

The structure of file is:

```
{"username":"test","email":"testtest@gmail.com"}
{"username":"test","email":"testtest@gmail.com"}
```

How can I iterate over the data.json file to search for a phrase identical to the parameter being passed? - 
Need to avoid adding the same data to the file again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate line by line and using callbacks, return true or false to indicate if the email exist or not. (The best approach is using a database or even bash commands to do this task but here is my solution for Node.js)

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream('./data.txt'),
});

/**
 * Check if a given email exist or not inside data.txt file
 * @param {String} email
 * @param {Function} callback
 * @returns {Object<error, emailIsDuplicated>}
 */
function existEmail(email, callback) {
  let callbackWasExecuted = false;

  lineReader.on('line', async (line) => {
    try {
      const jsonLine = JSON.parse(line);
      if (email === jsonLine.email) {
        callbackWasExecuted = true;
        return callback(null, true);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      callbackWasExecuted = true;
      return callback(new Error(`Error parsing to json next line: ${line}`));
    }
  });

  lineReader.on('close', () => callbackWasExecuted === false && callback(null, false));
}

existEmail('testtest1@gmail.com', (error, exist) => {
  if (error) {
    return console.error(error);
  }

  console.log(`Result exist email: ${exist}`);
});
```

Content for data.txt:

```
{"username":"test","email":"testtest@gmail.com"}
{"username":"test","email":"testtest1@gmail.com"}
```

Hope it helps. If something about the solution is not clear, let me know.

Comment: How can i transform this function to return: true (if email exist in file) or false(if email don't exist in file) ?  I need on depend it create condition with another instruction

Comment: Ok, i think about it and implemented: 
if(exist === true){
        console.log('exist')
        res.status(400).send('text')
      }
      if(exist === false){
        storeData(data,'./files/data.json');
        res.status(200).send('Ok')
      }